# I am trying to get unique words for each topic in R with best probability

Tags: r, lda

I get my list of words for each topic and their probabilities. I am trying to get unique words having the highest probability in topics.
I don't know how to do that.
Thank you

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data.

Comment: I have two files, one with 10 words in each topic and one with their probabilities. I want to keep only the words with highest probability when words appear in multiple topics. This is no code yet, that what I wanna try to do

Answer (score 0):

Here I have an example of what you can try: First you have to pass the result of your `lda()` function using `tidy()`, to extract the word-topic probabilities (beta), then using a `tidy` approach you can select by `slice_max`, the 20 words per topic with the highest probability.

```
# topic-word probabilities
word_topics_data <- tidy(summary_result_lda, matrix = "beta")

# First 20 topic-word
word_topics_data_list <- word_topics_data %>%
  group_by(topic) %>%
  slice_max(beta, n = 20) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(topic = paste("Topic", topic))
```

Comment: I get it, I am trying to keep the words with the highest probability when words appear in multiple topics.

Comment: Based on that, you need to add to the code the following: `group_by(word) %>% slice_max(topic, n = 5)`. And you will have the 5 topic where each word has the highest probability to appear in each topic.